# sync active directory domain services (ADDS) and azure active directory (AAD)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Hi I have a problem with Azure Active Directory Domain Services (ADDS)

When creating a new user in AAD the user is also visible from AADS. However when deleting a user from AAD the user is still visible from AADS but is marked disable. I expected the user to be deleted in AADS as well. Also when recreating the user in AAD (new id) the user is still marked disabled in AADS.

There is NO on-premise-AD and there is NO ADConnect installed.

Why is AAD and AADS not kept in sync as expected? And how do I force a re-sync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh I figured it out after reading the documentation more carefully. Apparently users that are deleted are put in the recycling bin for 30 days and they can be restored from there. The solution for me is to simply clear recycling-bin and to do so when deleting the users too.

```
$deletedUsers = Get-MsolUser -ReturnDeletedUsers -All
foreach($user in $deletedUsers)
{
    echo $user.DisplayName
    Remove-MsolUser -ObjectId $user.ObjectId -RemoveFromRecycleBin -Force
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the official documentation, after the initial synchronization between Azure AD and Azure AD DS, it typically takes about 20 minutes for updating changes. The update includes password changes or changes to attributes made in Azure AD.

Please see below for more details.

> User accounts, group memberships, and credential hashes are
>   synchronized from your Azure AD tenant to your Azure AD Domain
>   Services managed domain. This synchronization process is automatic.
>   You do not need to configure, monitor, or manage this synchronization
>   process. After the one-time initial synchronization of your directory
>   is complete, it typically takes about 20 minutes for changes made in
>   Azure AD to be reflected in your managed domain. This synchronization
>   interval applies to password changes or changes to attributes made in
>   Azure AD.

In addition, among the user attributes for synchronization, the user attribute **accountEnabled** in Azure AD is synchronized to user attribute **userAccountControl** in Azure AD DS. If the user is disabled in Azure AD, the value of userAccountControl is set to the **ACCOUNT_DISABLED** bit.

Based on the information above, I think Azure AD only has the permissions for creating and modifying users and groups in Azure AD DS during synchronization. It doesn't have the sufficient permission for deleting users.